# nasm x86 find largest and smallest and store in a register

Tags: linux, sorting, assembly, nasm

So far I understand how to get the largest number and store it in a register but I am unsure how to continue to get the smallest number? Any help would be much appreciated, or even a more efficient way of doing what I am currently doing. I am trying to store largest number in ax and smallest number in dx

```
    section .data

A  dw 1
B  dw 3
C  dw 8
D  dw 5

section .bss 

section .text 
    global _start

_start: mov eax,0       ;clear registers
       mov ecx,3 
       mov esi,A
       mov ax, [esi]
       add esi,2

again: cmp ax,[esi]
       jg cont
       mov ax,[esi]

cont: add esi,2
      dec ecx
      cmp ecx,0
      jnz again

exit: mov eax,1   
      mov ebx,0
      int 80h
```

Comment: By adding another comparison with another register after this comparison.

Comment: should i also restart my counter to 3? and decrement?

Comment: You can do it inside the same loop, no need to do another loop

Comment: ahh i see where would i compare  ? in again: ?

Comment: @joedirt as shown in the answer.

Comment: thank you! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it would to add another comparison after testing
if the current value is greater than the current largest (stored in ax), which would test if the current element is smaller than the current smallest (stored in dx). You would also need to initially set dx to be the same as the first element.

I've added the initial setting of the dx register and an extra section "isSmaller" which performs the check and sets the dx register if the current value being checked is smaller than the value stored in dx.

```
section .data

A  dw 1
B  dw 3
C  dw 8
D  dw 5

section .text 
    global _start

_start: mov eax,0       ;clear registers
       mov ecx,3 
       mov esi,A
       mov ax, [esi]    ; Initially set largest
       mov dx, [esi]    ; and initial smallest
       add esi,2

again: cmp ax,[esi]
       jg isSmaller
       mov ax,[esi]

isSmaller: cmp dx, [esi]
        jl cont
        mov dx, [esi]

cont: add esi,2
      dec ecx
      cmp ecx,0
      jnz again

exit: mov eax,1   
      mov ebx,0
      int 80h
```

Comment: So if i wanted to perform the same routine but with unsigned variables would I simply have to change jg to ja and jl to jb ?